# (android studio) I want add package

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4CgD.png)

I try to add dependency in android studio. I want add package androidx.biometric. But instead of add package, only copyright existed.

I try to search android studio homepage and google. but i don't detect solution

I want add package